# How do I extract everything inside the double-quotes from a list?

Tags: c#

I have the code:

```
class Program {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
   const string f = "../../../input.txt";
   List < string > lines = new List < string > ();
   using(StreamReader r = new StreamReader(f)) {
            string line;
            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null) {
                if (line.StartsWith("    <job_number") && line.EndsWith(">")) {
                    lines.Add(line);
                }
            }
        }
        foreach(string s in lines) {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

after the while loop, I run a condition to find any lines that start with some string and end with some string. This is how the string looks like:

```
<job_number "1234" />
<job_number "1829" />
```

How do I extract the numbers from inside the quote? At the moment the console prints out the whole line:

```
<job_number "1234" />
<job_number "1829" />
```

I want:

```
1234
1829
```

I've looked into Regex but it confuses me greatly.

**Edit:** I need to add that the file I am parsing is a systems configuration file which contains a lot of other data. I have managed to create a list called lines that gets the exact values that I need. I now need to throw some formatting in this list to get the values from the list (everything inside the quotes).

Comment: something like `"123"456"` possible?

Answer (score 3):

In your case, a simple regex match with `\d+` will do the job.

```
//...
while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var re = Regex.Match(line, @"(\d+)");
    if (re.Success) 
    {
        var val = re.Groups[1].Value; 
        lines.Add(val);
    }
}
//...
```

***EDIT:***

You can of course change the regex for your exact needs, for example:

```
var re = Regex.match(line, "job_number\\s\"(\\d+)\"");
```

might be more appropriate if your file contains other numbers as well.

Comment: Thanks - Where would I place this? I just started C# -

Comment: @MarcusAurelio Just replace the code within your while loop with the code within my while loop. Then everything should work as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. The file I am parsing also contains other data. The code above creates a List of the exact data I need. I then need to parse each line and get what is in the quotes.

Comment: @MarcusAurelio See my edit of how to specify your regex.

Answer (score 3):

If you are keen on LINQ:

```
var str = @"<job_number ""1234"" />";
var num = new string(str.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(num); // 1234
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `IndexOf` and `Substring` will get the job done in a manner of speed and memory and simplicity(part).

```
if (line.StartsWith("    <job_number") && line.EndsWith(">")) {
    int start = line.IndexOf("\"") + 1;
    int end = line.IndexOf("\"", start);

    if (start > 0 && end > 0)
    {
        string numberAsString = line.Substring(start, end - start);
        int number;
        if (int.TryParse(numberAsString, out number))
        {
            lines.Add(number);
            //Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Orel, thanks for that - But, I put that inbetween the if (line.StartsWith("    <job_number") && line.EndsWith(">")) but it threw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

If format of your string is invariable you can do it in one line with a simple `Split` method :

```
   string value = input.Split('"')[1];
```

For example :

```
   string[] s =
   {
       @"<job_number ""1234"" />",
       @"<job_number ""1829"" />"
   };
   for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) Console.Write(s[i].Split('"')[1] +",  ");
```

Output : `1234, 1829`

Answer (score 0):

The file you are parsing is practically XML  Why not just  go all the way and standardize the format to be xml complaint?

```
<Jobs>
 <Job Number="1234" />
 <Job Number="1235" />
</Jobs>
```

Then you could simply use Linq to XML to grab all the Job elements and enumerate their Number attribute.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");
    var numbers = from t in doc.Descendants("Job")
                  select t.Attribute("Number").Value;
    foreach (var number in numbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(number);
    }
```

Comment: `<job_number "1829" />` doesn't look like a valid xml tag

Comment: Obviously. I said "practically".  I'm suggesting just change the data format to be XML compliant and simplify the problem at hand.

Comment: Can't be changed unfortunately - it's system configuration file for a custom business app.

Comment: It's a rather odd format.  Did someone want to make it intentionally difficult to deal with? :)  Anyways for all the down voters out there, wouldn't you ask this question when peer reviewing someone's code?